# FFMPEG command to create subtitles isn't using the right font

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, python, fonts

I'm trying to use python to run an ffmpeg command to add subtitles onto a video, using an srt file.

I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -vf subtitles=testsrt.srt:force_style='Fontname=saveur-sans-bold.ttf,FontSize=24,PrimaryColour=&H03fcff,Alignment=10, Bold=5' raw_output2.mp4
```

While it creates the subtitles, it doesn't use the correct fon't (neither does it make it bold but that's less of an issue). What should I change to get the right font working?

Comment: Bear in mind that Python programming is off topic here and you should be working with proper ffmpeg commands. As your command is simply running ffmpeg after pushing all the parts together I have simplified it down for you, you can test that it still produces the same error condition and edit if necessary.

Comment: Try to copy `Fontname=saveur-sans-bold.ttf` to the folder in which you are executing the command (same folder of `output.mp4` file in your example). You may also try using full path (Windows example): `ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -vf "subtitles=testsrt.srt:force_style='Fontname=C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\saveur-sans-bold.ttf,FontSize=24,PrimaryColour=&H03fcff,Alignment=10,Bold=5'" raw_output2.mp4`